# Messages disappear once they have been sent. How can I make them stay?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, message

I have code for a messaging app here that uses js and php. The messages are sending and saving in the database properly, but they only appear on the screen for about a second and then disappear. I do not understand why this is happening because the messages are present in the table in my database. Could someone help me out?

index1.php

```html
</head>
<body onload="checkcookie(); update();">
<div id="whitebg"></div>
<div id="loginbox">
<h1>Pick a username:</h1>
<p><input type="text" name="pickusername" id="cusername" placeholder="Pick a username" class="msginput"></p>
<p class="buttonp"><button onclick="chooseusername()">Choose Username</button></p>
</div>
<div class="msg-container">
 <div class="header">Messenger</div>
 <div class="msg-area" id="msg-area"></div>
 <div class="bottom"><input type="text" name="msginput" class="msginput" id="msginput" onkeydown="if (event.keyCode == 13) sendmsg()" value="" placeholder="Enter your message here ... (Press enter to send message)"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var msginput = document.getElementById("msginput");
var msgarea = document.getElementById("msg-area");
function chooseusername() {
 var user = document.getElementById("cusername").value;
 document.cookie="messengerUname=" + user
 checkcookie()
}
function showlogin() {
 document.getElementById("whitebg").style.display = "inline-block";
 document.getElementById("loginbox").style.display = "inline-block";
}
function hideLogin() {
 document.getElementById("whitebg").style.display = "none";
 document.getElementById("loginbox").style.display = "none";
}
function checkcookie() {
 if (document.cookie.indexOf("messengerUname") == -1) {
  showlogin();
 } else {
  hideLogin();
 }
}
function getcookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}
function escapehtml(text) {
  return text
      .replace(/&/g, "&amp;")
      .replace(/</g, "&lt;")
      .replace(/>/g, "&gt;")
      .replace(/"/g, "&quot;")
      .replace(/'/g, "&#039;");
}
function update() {
 var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
 var username = getcookie("messengerUname");
 var output = "";
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
    var response = xmlhttp.responseText.split("\n")
    var rl = response.length
    var item = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < rl; i++) {
     item = response[i].split("\\")
     if (item[1] != undefined) {
      if (item[0] == username) {
       output += "<div class=\"msgc\" style=\"margin-bottom: 30px;\"> <div class=\"msg msgfrom\">" + item[1] + "</div> <div class=\"msgarr msgarrfrom\"></div> <div class=\"msgsentby msgsentbyfrom\">Sent by " + item[0] + "</div> </div>";
      } else {
       output += "<div class=\"msgc\"> <div class=\"msg\">" + item[1] + "</div> <div class=\"msgarr\"></div> <div class=\"msgsentby\">Sent by " + item[0] + "</div> </div>";
      }
     }
    }
    msgarea.innerHTML = output;
    msgarea.scrollTop = msgarea.scrollHeight;
   }
  }
       xmlhttp.open("GET","get-message.php?username=" + username,true);
       xmlhttp.send();
}
function sendmsg() {
 var message = msginput.value;
 if (message != "") {
  // alert(msgarea.innerHTML)
  // alert(getcookie("messengerUname"))
  var username = getcookie("messengerUname");
  var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
    message = escapehtml(message)
    msgarea.innerHTML += "<div class=\"msgc\" style=\"margin-bottom: 30px;\"> <div class=\"msg msgfrom\">" + message + "</div> <div class=\"msgarr msgarrfrom\"></div> <div class=\"msgsentby msgsentbyfrom\">Sent by " + username + "</div> </div>";
    msginput.value = "";
   }
  }
       xmlhttp.open("GET","update-message.php?username=" + username + "&message=" + message,true);
       xmlhttp.send();
   }
}
setInterval(function(){ update() }, 2500);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

update-message.php

```html
<?php

$db = new mysqli("localhost","root","","het_msg");

if ($db->connect_error) {
    die("couldnt connect");
}

$username = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_GET['username']));
$message = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_GET['message']));

if ($username == "" || $message == "") {
    die();
}

$result = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO messages VALUES('',?,?)");
$result->bind_param("ss", $username, $message);
$result->execute();
```

get-message.php

```html
<?php

$db = new mysqli("localhost","root","","het_msg");

if ($db->connect_error) {
    die("couldnt connect");
}

$username = stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($_GET['username']));

$result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM messages");
$result->execute();

$result = $result->get_result();

while($r = $resut->fetch_row()) {
    echo $r[1];
    echo "\\";
    echo $r[2];
    echo "\n";
}
```

Comment: `setInterval(function(){ update() }, 2500);` thats why

Comment: so i don't need that? doesnt it make sure that the page continues to refresh to get new messages?